# CL.exe not found when installing ionic using npm on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic, so any help will be highly appreciated.
I am trying to install ionic on windows 10, using npm. I have installed Cordova "successfully". I only got a warning about xmlbuilder expecting an older version of node, but it seemed everything went fine, as there were no errors after that.
However when I try to install ionic, it runs almost to the end, and then fails I think when it's trying to compile some files, which suggests that the downloads were successful. I think this is where everything starts to go wrong:

> ClCompile: CL.exe /c /I"C:\Users\Iyke.node-gyp\5.0.0\include\node"
>   /I"C:\Users\Iyke.node-gyp\5.0.0\src" /I"C:\Users\Iyke.node
>   -gyp\5.0.0\deps\uv\include" /I"C:\Users\Iyke.node-gyp\5.0.0\deps\v8\include" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX-
>   /Ox /Ob2 /Oi /Ot / Oy /GL /D NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass /D WIN32 /D
>   CRTSECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D CRTNONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D HASEXCE PTIONS=0
>   /D BUILDING_V8_SHARED=1 /D BUILDING_UV_SHARED=1 /D
>   "LIBSASS_VERSION=\"3.2.5\"" /GF /Gm- /MT /GS /Gy /fp:prec ise
>   /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR- /Fo"Release\obj\libsass\"
>   /Fd"Release\obj\libsass\libsass.pdb" /Gd /TP /wd4351 /wd4355 /wd4800
>   /wd4251 /errorReport:queue /GR /EHs /MP ....\src\libsass\ast.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\base64vlq .cpp ....\src\libsass\bind.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\constants.cpp ....\src\libsass\context.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\conte xtualize.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\contextualize_eval.cpp ....\src\libsass\cssize.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\emitter.cpp ... .\src\libsass\error_handling.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\eval.cpp ....\src\libsass\expand.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\extend.cpp ....\src\libsass\file.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\functions.cpp ....\src\libsass\inspect.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\json.cpp ....\src\libsass\lexer.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\listize.cpp ....\src\libsass\node.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\output.cpp ..\ ..\src\libsass\parser.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\plugins.cpp ....\src\libsass\position.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\prelexer.cpp ....\src\libsass\remove_placeholders.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\sass.cpp ....\src\libsass\sass2scss.cpp
>   ....\src\libsa ss\sass_context.cpp ....\src\libsass\sass_functions.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\sass_util.cpp ....\src\libsass\sass_value s.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\source_map.cpp ....\src\libsass\to_c.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\to_string.cpp ....\src\libsass\u nits.cpp
>   ....\src\libsass\utf8_string.cpp ....\src\libsass\util.cpp TRACKER :
>   error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the
>   file specified. [C:\Users\Iyke\AppData\
>   Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
>
> Done Building Project
>   "...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\nod
>   e-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Done Building Project
>   "...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\nod
>   e-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Done Building Project
>   "...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\nod
>   e-sass\build\binding.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.s
>   ln" (default target) (1) ->
>   "C:\Users\Iyke\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.v
>   cxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
>   "...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsa
>   ss.vcxproj" (default target) (3) -> (ClCompile target) -> TRACKER :
>   error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the
>   file specified. [...\AppDat
>   a\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
>
> 0 Warning(s) 1 Error(s) Time Elapsed 00:00:04.07 gyp ERR! build error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR!
>   stack at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23) gyp ERR! stack at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) gyp ERR! stack at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) gyp ERR! stack at
>   Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (internal/childprocess.js:200:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
>   "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library=" gyp ERR! cwd
>   ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\node-sass
>   gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3 gyp ERR! not ok
>   Build failed npm WARN install:node-sass@3.3.3 node-sass@3.3.3
>   postinstall: node scripts/build.js npm WARN install:node-sass@3.3.3
>   Exit status 1

Then it exits with an error code.

I have searched for the CL.exe file and it's here "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin" and here "Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin"

I don't know what else to do. Please help...

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded Node to 4.2.1, and it works. I still don't understand why 5.0 would not work, and would prefer an explanation if I can find one. At least now I can continue work.